# Modify records at one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Do you think this works well? I.e, do I need to close the database connection at the end? The goal is to be able to upsert and delete many records in one shoot.

Here is is an example HTTP POST request with JSON body to use it:

```
{"db" : "Memorise", "upsert" : [["Diagram", {"_id" : "abcd", "key1" : "value1"}]], "delete" : [["Diagram", {"_id" : "abc"}]]}
```

---

```
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var myServer = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{

    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function (chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end',function(){

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var databaseName = obj['db']

        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/" + databaseName, function(err, db) {

            if(!err) {

                var recordsToUpsert = obj['upsert']
                for (var i = 0; i < recordsToUpsert.length; i++) {
                var recordToUpsertAndCollection = recordsToUpsert[i]

                    var collectionName = recordToUpsertAndCollection[0];
                    var recordToUpsert = recordToUpsertAndCollection[1];

                    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
                    collection.save(recordToUpsert,{w:1}, {});
                };

                var conditionsToRemoveAndCollection = obj['delete']
                for (var i = 0; i < conditionsToRemoveAndCollection.length; i++) {
                var conditionToRemoveAndCollection = conditionsToRemoveAndCollection[i]

                    var collectionName = conditionToRemoveAndCollection[0];
                    var conditionToRemove = conditionToRemoveAndCollection[1];

                    var collection = db.collection(collectionName);
                    collection.remove(conditionToRemove,{w:1}, {});
                };

                response.writeHead(200)
                response.end()
            }
        });
    }); 
});
myServer.listen(3000)
```

Comment: About the connection, if you close or not. I got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495975/why-is-it-recommended-not-to-close-a-mongodb-connection-anywhere-in-node-js-code